# Bounds for addition of two absolutes

Tags: real-analysis, probability, random-variables

Given:

- x and y are some real constants
- $X_n$, $Y_n$ are two sequences of random variables, like $X_1$,$X_2$,... and $Y_1$,$Y_2$...
- $X_n$ converges in probability to x
- $Y_n$ converges in probability to y

Goal is to prove P($|X_n + Y_n -x -y| \geqslant \epsilon$) $\to$ 0, for any $\epsilon \gt 0$.

My question is regarding this statement in one of the steps for the solution(this is a solved problem in the book, but for my question, info included should be sufficient to not need the book):

For $|X_n + Y_n -x -y|$ to be as large as $\epsilon$, we need either $|X_n - x|$ or $|Y_n - x|$ (or both) to be at least $\epsilon/2$. Therefore, in terms of events, we have

{$|X_n + Y_n -x -y| \geqslant \epsilon$} $\subset$ {$|X_n - x| \geqslant \epsilon/2$} $\bigcup$ {$|Y_n - y| \geqslant \epsilon/2$}

How to prove this statement? I know triangle inequality gives an intuition but I am not able to prove that step formally.

FYI, the context: "Introduction to Probability by Dimitri Bertsekas and John N. Tsitsiklis" and am referring to solved problem 6 in Chapter 5.

Comment: Assume the converse. Then you immediately obtain a contradiction

Comment: Would you please elaborate @b00nheT

Comment: @b00nheT Are you referring to negation of $p \implies q$ as converse? I am referring to the tautology $(p \implies q) \iff[(p \wedge \neg q) \implies c]$ where c denotes contradiction

Comment: Wow, thanks @b00nheT for pointing me in the right direction. Though I assumed the negation of the implication instead of the converse. Then its straight forward triangle inequality to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: sorry for have caused such trouble :) glad you were able to solve it!